# pass value of radio button to textbox using modal

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to pass the selected radio button value to textbox in one page using modal ? im trying to make an attendance form for library, that the students will click the select purpose button and modal will appear they will choose either assignment or reading , after they select and click the confirm button the selected radio button will appear in the textbox. hope you can help me with this one. advance thanks.

heres my sample code:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form class="inputForm" >
<div class="inputbox">
<input type="text"  required/>
<label>Purpose</label>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Select Purpose" class="button1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Purpose:</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
       <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Assignment</label>
     </div>
     <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Reading</label>
     </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
     </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please share with us your php code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more like a client side (JavaScript) thing to me. [Live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/UaUSyn20VCN9cPEdyV9T?p=preview)

**1.** Include the following in your HTML:

```
<script>

    $('#modal_button').click(function() {

        var value = $("input:radio:checked").next().text();
        $('#purpose_input').val(value);
        $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
    });

</script>
```

Add `id="modal_button"` to your confirm button.

**2.** Change the form to:

```
<form class="inputForm" >
    <div class="inputbox">
        <input id="purpose_input" type="text"  required/>
        <label>Purpose</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

**3.** Change the submit button to:

```
<button class="button1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Select Purpose</button>
```

I hope it helps!